# Ubuntu alongside Windows

Tags: dual-boot

Is that possible to upgrade ubuntu to never versions when it is installed alongside windows? Now it is currently 12.04. Is that upgradable to 13.04 and future?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you use the normal upgrade process instead of reinstalling, upgrading will not change components critical for the boot process (whenever possible). This means, that it's very unlikely that the dual boot setup will be affected by upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can upgrade to 13.04 alongside windows, using CD or using command line also

do-release-upgrade -d